# LogisticRegression with GridSearchCV not converging

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, regression, grid-search

I'm trying to find the best parameters for a logistoic regression but I find that the "best estimator" doesn't converge.

Is there a way to specify that the estimator needs to converge to take it into account?

Here is my code.

```
# NO PCA
cv = GroupKFold(n_splits=10)
pipe = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('mnl', LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=True, multi_class="multinomial"))])

param_grid = [{'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs','sag', 'saga'],
               'mnl__C':[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5],
               'mnl__class_weight':[None,'balanced'],
              'mnl__max_iter':[1000,2000,3000],
              'mnl__penalty':['l1','l2']}]

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring=scoring, n_jobs=-1, refit='neg_log_loss', cv=cv, verbose=2, return_train_score=True)

grid.fit(X, y, groups=data.groups)


# WITH PCA
pipe = Pipeline([(
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('pca', PCA())
    ('mnl', mnl)])

param_grid = [{'pca__n_components':[None,15,30,45,65]
            'mnl__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs','sag', 'saga'],
              'mnl__max_iter':[1000,2000,3000],
             'mnl__C':[0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5],
              'mnl__class_weight':[None,'balanced'],
              'mnl__penalty':['l1','l2']}]

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='neg_log_loss', n_jobs=-1, refit=True, cv=cv, verbose=2)

grid.fit(X, y, groups=data.groups)
```

On the first case, the best estimator found is with an l2-lbfgs solver, with 1000 iterations, and it converges. The second one, the best estimator found is with saga solver and l1 penalty, 3000 iterations. I feel it has to do with the solver... but anyways, is there a straightforward way to state that it has to converge to accept it as best?

Comment: cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/490416/232706.
I think the last part of the question is suited best for here though.

Comment: Failure to converge in `LogisticRegression` gets raised as a warning (`sklearn.exceptions.ConvergenceWarning`).  You can elevate that to an Error with the `warnings` module.  And `GridSearchCV` swallows fitting errors and produces `np.NaN` as the score (by default).  But I just tried, and the warning-now-error doesn't get caught the same way.  But perhaps this will inspire someone else?

Comment: Give it more time/iterations, change algo and it will converge, probably